# Compare A Python List To A SQLAlchemy Collection

Tags: python, list, comparison, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

**How do I compare a Python list to a SQLAlchemy collection?**

I get the following error message

```
InvalidRequestError: Can't compare a collection to an object or collection; use contains() to test for membership
```

from this line

```
gr = AGroup.query.filter_by(users=sorted(members)).first()
```

Members is a list of AUser objects.

I want to check if any group exists with the same users as the members list.

However, since users is an sqlalchemy collection, this is not working.

Thank you. :)

Basic Class Structure

```
AGroup
- users

AUser
- name
```

Comment: how would you do it with a SQL query?

Comment: Have you tried what it says? "use contains() to test for membership"

Comment: Yeah, but that does not suit my needs. I dont want it to just contain the members and then maybe some other users. I want it to contain ONLY the members - which contains() does not check for. So hence, this did not work for me.

Comment: @zzzeek I ended up using just a little SQLAlchemy mixed in with Python (see my solution below and upvote if you like it), if you know of a better way to do this please let me know.

Comment: comparing a list in SQL is not that easy.   Here's an SO answer that talks about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017678/sql-server-compare-results-of-two-queries-that-should-be-identical

Comment: @zzzeek I already solved this issue in my answer below, however do you think my method is more or less efficient than the approach given in your link? Thanks.

Comment: depends on how much data we're dealing with.  if it scales how you need, i'd certainly stick with loading it in memory, but if i needed it to scale arbitrarily, i'd try to get a "compare lists in SQL" recipe to work, it would be somewhat complicated.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I solved the problem with the following code.

```
    groups = AGroup.query.all()
    for g in groups:
        if sorted(list(g.users)) == members:
            doSomething()
```

Comment: Whilst this works it is better to use an SQL query as loading many objects into memory could make your code very slow