# SQL Server - compare the results of two stored procedures that output multiple tables

Tags: sql-server

So, similar to ["SQL Server compare results of two queries that should be identical"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017678/sql-server-compare-results-of-two-queries-that-should-be-identical), I need to compare the output of two stored procedures to ensure the new version is generating equivalent output to the old version. The tricky part is that my SP outputs six tables of differing widths.

I started writing a hybrid version of them that would compare each of the tables individually, but it's a pretty complex SP, so I was hoping there was an easier way.

I tried using EXCEPT as in the linked question, but it looks like that will only compare one table to one other table.

Comment: Is there any relationship between the six tables?  Do they happen to be the same width (number of columns)?

Comment: No, different widths. Question updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy option 1: Output the stored procedure results to a text file (one per procedure version) and use a diff tool/editor to make sure they are the same.

Easy option 2: Write the stored procedure results to a table/temp table (per return table per procedure) and write sql to compare the results. Just count the rows in each result table and then do a count of the union (not union all) of both tables. Repeat for each result table.

Comment: Easy option 2 does not solve "I need to compare the output...".    However, if you output to a table/temptable, then i would simply use tablediff.exe tool (comes with SQL tools) to compare the tables.  I think option #1 is best/easiest answer.

Comment: Well option 2 would solve it too. Version 2 is my preferred way because it works on bigger outputs too in a fast way.

Answer (score 2):

You can capture multiple result sets in .NET (C# or VB) quite easily. You can create a `DataAdapter` and `DataSet`, and use the `DataAdapter.Fill()` method to populate the `DataSet`. Each result set will be stored as a `DataTable` within that `DataSet`. Then you just need to loop through the `DataTables` collection in each `DataSet` and compare them. You can find more info on this MSDN page: [Populating a DataSet from a DataAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z.aspx)

This can be done in either SQLCLR if you want to run it as a stored procedure or user-defined function, OR it can be a stand-alone console application. Running it as a SQLCLR stored procedure is quite convenient, but given that you will be stored all results for all 6 result sets, and for *both* stored procedures that you are testing, that might require too much memory. In that case, the console app is the the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is add an additional parameter to your both of (New/old) stored procedures to handle which result it should return like.

```
Exec usp_proc @var1 , @var2 , @ResultSet = 1
```

The above execution should return the first result set and if you pass `@ResultSet = 2` it should return second result set and so on.....

do this with both stored procedure and then compare the result sets group by group (using except will do the trick).

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, output parameters can't be table-valued.